Inventory variables reused with next inventory
I have been defining inventories like this -- this is a single file, say production.yml:
database:
  vars:
    security_access_users:
      - moe
      - curly
      - larry
    sudo_users:
      - username: moe
  hosts:
    host_b:

Then I might have another inventory file with another inventory, say, staging.yml:
database: 
  vars:
    security_access_users:
      - huey
      - dewey
      - louie
    sudo_users:
      - username: huey
  hosts:
    host_a:

If I run both inventories at once with -i production.yml and -i staging.yml in the same command line, the variables are not isolated within each inventory.
Is this expected? I was surprised the variables weren't cleared.
Is there a better way to do this to keep the variables isolated between inventories? The roles these variables are for have defaults and I would have expected those defaults to be used.
edit: looks like merging policy is the issue:

By default, Ansible merges groups at the same parent/child level in ASCII order, and variables from the last group loaded overwrite variables from the previous groups. For example, an a_group will be merged with b_group and b_group vars that match will overwrite the ones in a_group.


So in your examples webservers and databases share the same hosts?

"Is this expected?", yes. See Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable? "Is there a better way to do this to keep the variables isolated between inventories?", yes, group_vars. See How to build your inventory - Organizing host and group variables.

@U880D group_vars are already being used in the OP's example. I believe the question is related to Ansible design itself - the fact that it merges the host variables if the hosts are the same within different groups keeps surprising people for almost 10 years (well, not exactly merges, but still): https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9065

@AlexanderPletnev No, different hosts.  Each group in the inventory has unique hosts.

I cannot reproduce your issue. Are you sure there is not somewhere you are accidentally making webservers a child of database?  Or defining those variable in a group_vars file per mistake? My minimal no-repro: https://gist.github.com/b-enoit-be/a7a13fe731fab00b8d638ad269df0168

Also mind that filiation make you inherit from variables, so, if you have groups defined as linux is child of database and webserver child of linux, then, you inherit from those as there are coming from the grandparent group.

I've rewritten the question.  I misunderstood the problem, and I think it is due to sharing group names across inventories when running at the same time.

This is the expected behavior.
From Assigning a variable to many machines: group variables:

Group variables are a convenient way to apply variables to multiple hosts at once. Before executing, however, Ansible always flattens variables, including inventory variables, to the host level. If a host is a member of multiple groups, Ansible reads variable values from all of those groups. If you assign different values to the same variable in different groups, Ansible chooses which value to use based on internal rules for merging.


The roles these variables are for have defaults and I would have expected those defaults to be used.

Role defaults have lower precedence than the inventory variables. Otherwise we wouldn't have an ability to override them. If your roles have some variables that should not be overridden, consider moving them to role vars.

Is there a better way to do this to keep the variables isolated between inventories?

I would say it depends on your playbooks/roles implementation. There are nearly 20 levels of variable precedence, I think it's better to check what option would suit your needs more. Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable? section of Ansible documentation contains more details about this.

Also, from the section on merging: By default, Ansible merges groups at the same parent/child level in ASCII order, and variables from the last group loaded overwrite variables from the previous groups. For example, an a_group will be merged with b_group and b_group vars that match will overwrite the ones in a_group.

I think I've come to an understanding -- multiple -i's don't isolate the inventory variables during the run. They're merged and group vars are just merged / overwritten.
Instead, I need to move the variables to their own group for the specific inventory and put the hosts in two groups.
huey_development: 
  vars:
    security_access_users:
      - huey
      - dewey
      - louie
    sudo_users:
      - username: huey
  hosts:
    host_a:

database:
  hosts:
    host_a:

And then make another one for moe_development with host_b
